# Why does the equality $\int \mathbf{r}\times \nabla f d\nu=0$ holds?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, vectors

My question comes from **Problem 4. Classical laws for angular motion** of  [Practical Quantum Mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540650350).

And the Prob.4 is that,

> To show that the classical relation between angular momentum $\mathbf{L}=\mathbf{r}\times \mathbf{p}$ and torque $\mathbf{T}=\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{F}$(where $\mathbf{p}$ stands for linear momentum and $\mathbf{F}$ for force),
>   $$
> \frac{d\mathbf{L}}{dt}=\mathbf{T},
> $$
>   still holds for the space averages in quantum mechanics.

In the solution, the author applied one equation, i.e.

$$
\iiint (\mathbf{r}\times \nabla f) d\nu=0
$$
where $\mathbf{r}=x\hat{i}+y\hat j+z\hat k$, and he said that the equality is a "general vector rule". However, I couldn't find this equality anywhere(include vector analysis tetbooks, wikipedia and this site).

I have also try to prove that equality holds. According the rule $\nabla\times (f\mathbf{A})=f\nabla\times \mathbf{A}+\nabla f \times \mathbf{A}$, I got 
$$
\mathbf{r}\times \nabla f=-\nabla\times (f\mathbf{r})
$$
but I don't know what should I do to prove that the integration is zero.
So, I need help.

Comment: Integration of a total derivative is a boundary term. The author must be assuming that $f{\bf r}$ vanishes on the boundaries of the volume over which he is integrating, i.e. at infinity.

Comment: I cannot believe that you couldn't find this anywhere, as it seems a rather straightforward application of [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_theorem).

Comment: @ACuriousMind No, Stokes theorem couldn't tell me why that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any volume integral of curl $\mathbf A$:

$$
\int_V \nabla\times \mathbf A \,dV
$$

can be calculated also as surface integral of $\mathbf A$:

$$
\oint_\Sigma d\boldsymbol\Sigma\times\mathbf{A};
$$

here $\Sigma$ is boundary of the region and $d\boldsymbol \Sigma = \mathbf nd\Sigma$ is vector whose magnitude is that of area $d \Sigma$ has direction of normal to the surface and is oriented outwards.

If magnitude of $\mathbf n \times \mathbf A$ is zero at every point of some closed boundary surface, surface integral over this boundary will be zero.

Whether this is so depends on the physical situation considered. For example, it is true if $\mathbf A$ is electrostatic field and the boundary is in metal, since field vanishes in metal. It isn't true if $\mathbf A$ is magnetic field of simple circuit and boundary is in vacuum, since the field vanishes nowhere; it only decays with distance.

If the decay is fast enough though, the above integral may have limit 0 as the boundary is expanded to infinity.

Your integral has this form if we take $\mathbf A=f\mathbf r$. So, the condition of validity of the relation is either 1) $f$ vanishes on some closed boundary surface, or 2) $f$ decays with distance rapidly enough.

Comment: Yes, we suppose that $f$ satisfy the two conditions.